# Action doesn't update the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

|I have the following component based on [this](https://gist.github.com/robertgonzales/e54699212da497740845712f3648d98c):

```
**WarningModal.js**

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {Alert, No} from './pure/Icons/Icons';
import Button from './pure/Button/Button';
import Modal from './pure/Modal/Modal';

import {setWarning} from '../actions/app/appActions';

import configureStore from '../store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

export const WarningModal = (props) => {
    const {message, withCleanup} = props;
    const [
        title,
        text,
        leave,
        cancel
    ] = message.split('|');

    const handleOnClick = () => {
        props.setWarning(false);
        withCleanup(true);
    }

    return(
        <Modal>
            <header>{title}</header>
            <p>{text}</p>
            <Alert />
            <div className="modal__buttons-wrapper modal__buttons-wrapper--center">
                <button 
                    onClick={() => withCleanup(false)} 
                    className="button modal__close-button button--icon button--icon-only button--text-link"
                >
                    <No />
                </button>
                <Button id="leave-warning-button" className="button--transparent-bg" onClick={() => handleOnClick()}>{leave}</Button>
                <Button id="cancel-warning-button" onClick={() => withCleanup(false)}>{cancel}</Button>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}

WarningModal.propTypes = {
    withCleanup: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    setWarning: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        isWarning: state.app.isWarning
    }
};

const WarningModalContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, {
    setWarning
})(WarningModal);




export default (message, callback) => {
    const modal = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(modal);

    const withCleanup = (answer) => {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(modal);
        document.body.removeChild(modal);
        callback(answer);
    };

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <WarningModalContainer 
                message={message} 
                withCleanup={withCleanup} 
            />
        </Provider>,
        modal
    );
};
```

the issue I have is that 'setWarning' doesn't update the state, it does get called as I have a debugger inside the action and the reducer but the actual property doesn't not change to 'false' when:

```
props.setWarning(false);
```

gets called.

I use the following to trigger the custom modal:

```
    const togglePromptCondition = 
        location.hash === '#access-templates' || location.hash === '#security-groups' 
            ? promptCondition
            : isFormDirty || isWarning;

<Prompt message={promptMessage} when={togglePromptCondition} />
```

To test this even further I have added 2 buttons in the application to toggle 'isWarning' (the state property I am talking about) and it works as expected.

I think that although WarningModal is connected in actual fact it isn't.

**REDUCER**

```
...
    case SET_WARNING:
        console.log('reducer called: ', action)
        return {
            ...state,
            isWarning: action.payload 
        };
...
```

**ACTION**

```
...
export const setWarning = status => {
    console.log('action called')
    return {
        type: SET_WARNING,
        payload: status
    }
};
...
```

**UPDATE**

After having to incorporates the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isWarning: state.app.isWarning
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        setWarning: (status) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_WARNING', payload: status })
    }
};
```

I am now getting:

[image]

Maybe [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-navigation-prompt#api-1) could help?

Comment: Can you show your reducer? The issue is likely there.

Comment: @Colin I have updated the code with the reducer and action. Thanks

Comment: Do you have `const SET_WARNING = 'SET_WARNING'` defined?

Comment: `console.log('action called')`, what's the `status` if you log it there?

Comment: @Colin that doesn't get called once the modal is loaded

Comment: @Colin although the component is connected the method doesn't seem to update the store/state once the WarningModal is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispatch the actions in the action creator and the type of the action to dispatch should be always string.

Try this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
   console.log(state)
   return {
       isWarning: state.app.isWarning
   }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   console.log(dispatch)
   return {
       setWarning: (status) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_WARNING', payload: status })
   }
};

const WarningModalContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WarningModal);
```

**REDUCER**

```
...
    case 'SET_WARNING':
        console.log('reducer called: ', action)
        return {
            ...state,
            isWarning: action.payload 
        };
...
```

Comment: Hi, that's great but now I am getting an error when 'handleOnClick' is called.

Comment: Why would this make a difference if `SET_WARNING = 'SET_WARNING'`?

Comment: That will help too @Colin